# Encontrar uma letra em caixa alta no texto

Tags: c#, vb.net

Estou fazendo umas verificações de texto para senha.

Já localizei para caractere especial mas não achei para letra em caixa alta.

Usei Regex. Por exemplo se o texto conter "teste" retorna falso e se conter "tesTE" retorna verdadeiro.

Alguém sabe me dizer? Se funciona com o Regex também?

Utilizei este para verificar se o meu campo senha tem um caractere especial

```
ExisteCaracterEspecial = Regex.IsMatch(txt_senha.Text, ("[\[\]\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\\~`\!@#%&\-_+={}'""<>:;, ]{1,}"));
```

Estou usando VB.NET

Comment: @rubStackOverflow Acho que se o AP colocou a tag `C#` é porque aceita resposta em qualquer uma das linguagens. Não teria porque remover a tag.

Comment: Entendido @jbueno

Comment: @rubStackOverflow Eu acho, né :p Vamos ver o que ele diz

Comment: Melhor passar do que faltar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível fazer isso usando o `Any` do LINQ também.

#### Em VB.NET

- Com LINQ

  ```
  Dim existeMaiuscula As Boolean = senha.Any(Function(c) Char.IsUpper(c))
  ```
- Com Regex

  ```
  Dim existeMaiuscula As Boolean = Regex.IsMatch(senha, "\p{Lu}")
  ```

#### Em C#

- Com LINQ

  ```
  var existeMaiuscula = senha.Any(c => Char.IsUpper(c));
  ```
- Com Regex

  ```
  var existeMaiuscula = Regex.IsMatch(senha, @"\p{Lu}");
  ```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente @jbueno muito obrigado!